# Style React-Hook-Form Controller with Styled-Component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-hook-form

I am trying to style the NumberFormat `Controller` found in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx?file=/src/styles.css:474-649 with a **styled-component**.

In the example the only thing I have to change is the `.input` class in the `styles.css` file.

I did see that the `Controller` extends "input" among others. I still can not wrap my head around how I should implement it.

What I did was the following:

```
const NumericAndDateInput = styled.div`
    .input {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 30%;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
     }
 `;
```

and within the `return()` of my functional component

```
<NumericAndDateInput>
  <Controller
    as={NumberFormat}
    thousandSeparator
    name={`rate${groupIndex + 1}`}
    control={control}
    />
</NumericAndDateInput>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of NumberFormat please ?

Comment: @Joris The NumberFormat comes from the react-hook-form library. This part is not implemented by me. At stated above, you may also find an example about it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx?file=/src/index.js